# why is user 'nobody' listed as a user on my iMAC?

Tags: user-account

```
$ dscl . list /users
_timed
_timezone
_tokend
_trustevaluationagent
_unknown
_update_sharing
_usbmuxd
_uucp
_warmd
_webauthserver
_windowserver
_www
_wwwproxy
_xserverdocs
daemon
Guest
nobody
Owner
Rob
root
```

Why is there a user called `nobody`?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/186568/9454

Comment: Does nobody log in? Why does nobody log in? :)

Comment: This is also common for other Unix-like systems, for example with NFS files are normally mapped to that user if you should not be able to control them (root squash)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Those accounts are for systems processes and to restrict access to things like files and resources by group or user.

Comment: so user 'nobody' is a legit MACOS generated User?

Comment: Totally. Drop me your macOS build / version and I can dump the correct list for you. Nobody is everywhere, though. An ubiquitous non-account in most unixen @robertodulce

Comment: @bmike "Nobody is everywhere" --- channeling Odysseus and the Cyclops?

Comment: I am a man of twists and turns and appreciate you noticing that human condition @CarlWitthoft

Comment: @robertodulce: Most Unix and Linux systems have a `nobody` user; it's 100% standard for Unix systems.  e.g. [What is nobody user and group?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/186568) / [What is the purpose of the 'nobody' user?](https://askubuntu.com/q/329714).  On my Arch GNU/Linux system, it has UID=99, and shell `/usr/bin/nologin`.

Answer (score 30):

There are a lot of places in the OS where something has to be assigned to *some* user account. Each file and directory must be owned by some user account, every process (program) running must be running *as* some user account, etc. The "nobody" account serves mostly as a placeholder for files, processes, etc that don't really belong to any "real" account (even one of the other system accounts in the list).

Essentially, the "nobody" account serves as a way to restrict permissions and access to/from things that don't really belong to any "real" account.

It's also not unique to macOS at all; you'll find it (or an equivalent) on any unix/linux system, and probably many other OSes I'm less familiar with.